# Azure Data Facotry Dataflow Rest Source Post Does Not Work

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

Im using a rest connector in my dataflow to query an api end point. The endpoint takes a post request with a json body specifying the information you want back. For some reason when I use a rest connector, the post request always fails and I cant import a projection for my data. When I use other things such as a web activity in the pipeline, or just a regular http connector, the request works. However, I can't use either of those options in my dataflow. Could someone help to see what is wrong with my rest connector?
[Linked service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RPhZ.jpg) [Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRcvh.jpg) [Request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6CjD.jpg) [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Slb9.jpg)

Comment: Can you please check if in your headers you specify the correct Content-Type?

Comment: They do, it is straight from the documentation and the request works outside of the dataflows (ie. postman and in adf with http connector)